# how to get dates from text in c#

Tags: c#

From a document I want to find and get the dates, and the date will be in a different format in each document. How do I achieve that in C#?

Comment: What is this document, a text file? MS word file? Can you please post an example of the input you will have and the output you expect?

Comment: it is a text file. from that i want to extract the date.

Answer (score 4):

You should rather have a look at using [DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

> **DateTime.TryParse Method** Converts the specified string representation of
>   a date and time to its DateTime
>   equivalent and returns a value that
>   indicates whether the conversion
>   succeeded.
>
> **DateTime.TryParseExact Method** Converts the specified string
>   representation of a date and time to
>   its DateTime equivalent using the
>   specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information,
>   and style. The format of the string
>   representation must match at least one
>   of the specified formats exactly. The
>   method returns a value that indicates
>   whether the conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTime.ParseExact(string, format) to create a DateTime from a formatted string.

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx for more details.

Comment: In my case i've a document. from that i want to extract the date. That document contains not only a date, it will have text,email etc.